# Understanding of CSS: Position

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a question about the CSS property: Position

As I was creating a page that looks this:
[image]

As you can see, there is a table and div next to each other. The following codes shows that how I achieve this:
Code Structure:

```
<div className="daily-task-view">
  <table{...getTableProps()}>
  <thead >
    {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
      <tr className="table-header-row"{...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
        {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
          <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())} className={
              column.isSorted
                ? column.isSortedDesc
                  ? "sort-desc"
                  : "sort-asc"
                : ""
            } ><h5 className="table-header-head"><b>{column.render("Header")}
              </b></h5></th> 
        ))}
      </tr>
    ))}
  </thead>
  <tbody  {...getTableBodyProps()}>
    {page.map((row, i) => {
      prepareRow(row);
      return (
        <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
          {row.cells.map(cell => {
            return <td className="table-content"  {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
          })}
        </tr>
      );
    })}
  </tbody>
</table>
<div className="search">
  <GlobalFilter filter={globalFilter} setFilter={setGlobalFilter}/>
  <Button variant="success" className="button-to-add-dailytask">Add Daily Task</Button>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.search{
margin-left:200px;
border-radius: 20px;
background-color: white;
width:fit-content;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 780px;
}
.daily-task-view{
padding-top: 10px; 
 padding-left: 20px;
 position: relative;}
```

So far, the CSS that I have did presented the view that I want **BUT** when I **Zoom In or Zoom Out**, The Search which is the div tag didn't follow the action like moving the same way as the table been moving instead it didn't move and stick at that position that I set.

As I want the table and div be together so that that can act the same way (such as Zoom in/Zoom out)

What can I do, I used Absolute and Relative. Based on my understanding, both need to be together but in my case, it doesn't act that way.

Is my understanding of these 2 properties wrong?

Please Help

Comment: I didn't quite understood the question BUT, in my opinion I would use a container flex to achieve this design and not a css position. If your question is about understanding positions in CSS I suggest you take a look at this link : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Comment: since the search div is absolutely positioned 780px from the left, it will always be 780px from the left, and thus "breaks" on zoom in / out as the other element changes size. You could give them both a relative position value, as well as inline-block to make them appear next to each other (if set widths in percentage). Or you could use flex as mentioned by @MathieuRios

Comment: Hi @knutagard , I try to use the method but is still not working, and whenever I triggered the function the search will be moving as well

So what I wanted to do is I wanted to put the Search component next to the table component and when I zoom in or out the Search component should be always be next to the table

Comment: I also tried the method that @MathieuRios suggested, yes it still the same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code now, you have the .search div inside the .daily-task-view one. This might be the issue

Here is an example of how you could achieve what I think you have in mind, by using a wrapper div and giving that display: flex, and then making .daily-task-view + .search separate and not .search inside the other. In my example I have also set widths for the div's, but it could be fit-content as well, or what you prefer.

https://codepen.io/akmalmo/pen/BapeXra

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper"><div class="daily-task-view">
  Table
</div>
<div class="search">
  Search
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{display:flex}
.search{
border-radius: 20px;
width:40%;background:red;
margin-left:20px;}
.daily-task-view{
padding-top: 10px;width:60%;background:blue;}

.daily-task-view, .search{padding:20px;}
```

Does this help?

Comment: No worries. Perhaps position sticky would be nice to play around with in that design as well